# Matrix norms involving singular values

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

The induced 2-norm of a $m \times n$ matrix $A$ is known as $$ ||A||_2 = \underset{||x||=1}{\text{max}} ||Ax||_2 = \sigma_1,$$
where $\sigma_1$ is the largest singular value of $A$.

Then, is it possible to define a norm s.t. $||A||$ equals the $p$-th largest singular value $\sigma_p$ of $A$ for all $p \in \{1,2,...,\text{min}(m,n)\}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Take $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$. We'd have $A$'s norm to be $0$ and yet $A$ isn't the null matrix.